# FTP file auto commit to Bitbucket or Gitlab

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket, gitlab

Is it a way when the FTP got a change then some tool will commit and push to Bitbucket or Gitlab,i looked Google,most of the toll is `Git > FTP`,but i want is `FTP > Git`

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Linux machine then that would be simple. You must have something like [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and git to achieve what you want. I wrote a [similar script](https://github.com/geraldvillorente/rsynctify) 2 years ago. What is does is it will listen to the changes on a particular directory and when something changed it will run rsync. You can just replace rsync by Git.

There is a similar script on Python also: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-notify/0.3.1